# Как бы вы произвели проверку массива, который содержит список массивов с значениями для проверки

Tags: php, массивы

Массив может выглядить так, причем количество ключей в следующем внутреннем массиве может отличаться. По окончанию проверки каждого значения, массив должен выглядить также. Учитывать стоит, что значение может быть текстовым.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2008
            [faculty] => 4
            [program] => 10
            [...] => ...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [agree] => on 
            [year] => 2010
            [faculty] => 47
            [program] => 4
            [...] => ...
        )
     ...
)
```

Писать код не нужно, достаточно рассказать на словах или в крайнем случае рассказ дополнить псевдокодом.

Для чего мне это ? Просто интересно ) Сам столкнулся, с подобным массивом и лучшего решения чем, как пройтись циклом с условными конструкциями if не придумал...

Comment: А на что проверка?

Comment: [array_merge](http://php.net/array-merge) ([array_intersect](http://php.net/array-intersect), [array_diff](http://php.net/array-diff), etc)?

Comment: Да возможно не корректно поставлен вопрос. Проверка может быть, как на то что эти данные вовсе есть под определенным ключем массива (т.е. обязательные), так на тип данных и по регулярным выражениями. Все значения одинаково не проверяются.

Answer (score 3):

Функция `in_array()` проверяет, присутствует ли в массиве заданный элемент. Если присутствует, возвращает значение `true`, иначе `false`.
   Синтаксис функции:

```
bool in_array(mexed элемент, array массив)
```

`array_keys()` эта функция возвращает массив, содержащий все ключи исходного массива, переданного в качестве параметра. Если при вызове задаётся дополнительный параметр "искомый элемент" возвращаются только ключи, которым соответствует заданное значение; в противном случае возвращается все ключи массива.
   Синтаксис функции:

```
array array_keys(array массив, [, mixed искомый_элемент])
```

`array_values()` функция возвращает массив, состоящий из всех значений исходного массива, переданного в качестве параметра.
   Синтаксис функции:

```
array array_values(array массив)
```

Можно через эти функции делать поиск. Создать массив элементов которые надо проверить. и в цикле искать этими функциями каждый элемент или другие функции поиска в массиве элементов содержащихся в массиве)

Answer (score 0):

А я бы воспользовался фукнцией `array_filter()` с `callback`.

Если `$array` - исходный массив, то

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($elem) {
    [здесь проверять все условия к конкретному подмассиву
    если условия выполняются - return true; если не выполняются - return false;
    тут уже ограничений нет. Например:
    if ($elem["agree"]!="on") return false;
    if (!array_key_exists("whatever", $elem)) return false;
    if ($elem["year"]>date('Y')) return false;
    вобщем все, что угодно....
});
```

В результате `$filtered` будут только те записи, в которых проверочный `callback` вернул `true`.